# FCM - duplicate notifications on iOS devices

Tags: ios, node.js, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Firebase admin SDK (Node.js) to send topic messages.
Some of our iOS users receive the message twice (every time).

In the past, the notifications implementation was done using apns, so in order to support old users I used [batchImport](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#manage_relationship_maps_for_multiple_app_instances) to map iOS device tokens to Firebase registration ids.
Once a valid registration id is available I subscribe the client to a topic.
My guess is that old users were registered to firebase from the server, and after updating the app they registered to firebase from the client, which caused duplicate registrations of the same apns device token.